# Get H2 and specific elements from html response

Tags: jquery, parsing, find, element

I have a problem which can be solved easily i think.I want to get the h2 values and specific id or class values from a html response of an external website here is my script i also tried it with getting the title of the website but nothing works need some help here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var your_url = 'http://www.moebelundkonsorten.de';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// jquery.xdomainajax.js  ------ from padolsey

jQuery.ajax = (function(_ajax){

var protocol = location.protocol,
    hostname = location.hostname,
    exRegex = RegExp(protocol + '//' + hostname),
    YQL = 'http' + (/^https/.test(protocol)?'s':'') + '://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?callback=?',
    query = 'select * from html where url="{URL}" and xpath="*"';

function isExternal(url) {
    return !exRegex.test(url) && /:\/\//.test(url);
}

return function(o) {

    var url = o.url;

    if ( /get/i.test(o.type) && !/json/i.test(o.dataType) && isExternal(url) ) {

        // Manipulate options so that JSONP-x request is made to YQL

        o.url = YQL;
        o.dataType = 'json';

        o.data = {
            q: query.replace(
                '{URL}',
                url + (o.data ?
                    (/\?/.test(url) ? '&' : '?') + jQuery.param(o.data)
                : '')
            ),
            format: 'xml'
        };

        // Since it's a JSONP request
        // complete === success
        if (!o.success && o.complete) {
            o.success = o.complete;
            delete o.complete;
        }

        o.success = (function(_success){
            return function(data) {

                if (_success) {
                    // Fake XHR callback.
                    _success.call(this, {
                        responseText: data.results[0]
                            // YQL screws with <script>s
                            // Get rid of them
                            .replace(/<script[^>]+?\/>|<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/gi, '')
                    }, 'success');
                }

            };
        })(o.success);

    }

    return _ajax.apply(this, arguments);

};

})(jQuery.ajax);



$.ajax({
url: your_url,
type: 'GET',
success: function(res) {
    var text = res.responseText;
    // then you can manipulate your text as you wish
$(text).find("title").text();

    alert(text);
}
});

</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vc2kgu92/

Comment: Where you facing issue? in ajax call ?

Comment: Please give more detail than 'nothing works'. Are there any errors in the console? Have you made any attempt to debug at all? If so, what?

Comment: @MokshShah yes fiddled it here my friend https://jsfiddle.net/vc2kgu92/

Comment: grab the url html value but cant get the title or heading tags pls look at js fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

Update your ajax call with this

```
       $.ajax({
    url: your_url,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        var text = res.responseText;
        //Here you will get title element, then you may fetch all its attributes

        var titleElement = $(text).filter("title");
        alert($(titleElement).html());

        console.log(text);
    }
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vc2kgu92/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this fiddle. I put your ajax return in `div.hide`. And output `title` and `h2` at div.output

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vc2kgu92/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery.parseHTML()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) you can get elements from HTML string, which is added from jQuery version 1.8. See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vc2kgu92/5/)

```
 var html = $.parseHTML(HTMLstring);
 console.log($(html).filter("title")[0].innerHTML);
```